# Problemas a la hora de que me detecte las funciones de mi controller

Tags: angularjs

Estoy intentando hacer un Menu (con primero, segundo y postre) y me gustaria introducir un `input` para introducir un nuevo plato en el `array` que he creado (para mostrarlo con `ng-repeat`).

Parece que no me entra dentro de las funciones que creo en el controler y no me hace nada. No me muestra ningun error...

Me estoy quedando sin ideas. Os dejo el codigo HTML y el del Angular.js.

> Codigo HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular JS</title>
</head>
<!-- Angular JS -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="myApp">
     <div  ng-controller="MenuController">
        <ul>

            <h1>Menu</h1>
            <h2>Primer Plato</h2>

            <li ng-repeat="x in menu.primero">
                    {{ x }}

            </li>
            <input type="text" ng-model="cambiarPrimero" ng-keypress="MenuController.keyPressOnForm($event)" />
            <h2>Segundo Plato</h2>

            <li ng-repeat="x in menu.segundo">
                    {{ x }}
            </li>

            <h2>Postre</h2>

            <li ng-repeat="x in menu.postre">
                    {{ x }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> Codigo AngularJS (guardarlo en la raiz como app.js)

```
var app =  angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("MenuController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.menu= {
      primero: ['sopa', 'paella','calamares'],
      segundo: ['carne','pescado','tortilla'],
      postre: ['fruta','yogur']
    };



    var keyPressOnForm = function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) { //la key 13 es el enter
        function updatePlato(){
            $scope.menu.primero.push($scope.cambiarPrimero.text);
        }
        updatePlato();
      }
    }
});
```

Toda idea es buena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias probra realizando las siguientes modificaciones, en tú html :

`ng-keypress="keyPressOnForm($event)`

En tu controller :

`$scope.keyPressOnForm = function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) { //la key 13 es el enter
        function updatePlato(){
            $scope.menu.primero.push($scope.cambiarPrimero);
        }
        updatePlato();
      }
    }`

Al utilizar el $scope.keyPressOnForm lo están dando alcance a la función dentro de tú controller.

Comment: No funciona. Gracias

Comment: si le quitas el .text funciona. Edita tu respuesta  y te lo confirmo

Comment: Excelente. Hecho.